# flutter make raised button change after future return value

Tags: flutter

I have a raised button that kicks off my fingerprint authentication, when the Future returns I want to be able to change the Raised Button to new text and new onPressed method to complete the required authentication. I have given the Raised Button a key but can not find how to act upon that button to change it.  Is it possible?  Anyone have examples of it?

I tried to create new Raised Button with same key based on if the user is authenticated, but it did not change anything.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing the [Flutter Interactivity Tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/).

Once the `Future` completes you can call `setState` to tell Flutter to rebuild your `StatefulWidget`. And in your `build()` method, you can use the authenticated status of the user to construct a different `RaisedButton`.

Here's some example code that does this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Local Auth Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _authenticated = false;

  Future<Null> _authenticate() async {
    final LocalAuthentication auth = new LocalAuthentication();
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate',
        useErrorDialogs: true);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _authenticated = authenticated;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildAuthButton() {
    assert(!_authenticated);
    return new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text('Authenticate'),
      onPressed: _authenticate,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContinueButton() {
    assert(_authenticated);
    return new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text('Continue'),
      onPressed: () {
        // Do something now that the user is authenticated
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Interactivity Tutoral'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: _authenticated ? _buildContinueButton() : _buildAuthButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use FutureBuilder, just return one widget or the other based on whether the Future is complete

```
  new FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: your_future,
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                else
                  return new Text(
                    'Your data: ${snapshot.data}',
                  );
            }
      })
```